# The confusion of opening a project in xcode 4

Tags: xcode

When I open a project in Xcode 4, it will automatically unfold all groups even though these groups weren't expanded the last time I closed the project. Why? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Never seen this before, but if it makes it any better, you can `Alt + click` on the arrows to expand/contract all the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to reproduce this:

Double click on one of your app file, it is gonna open in a new naked editor.
Close the the Xcode app, before closing the recent opened window.
Close Xcode.
Open your app again, and here we are.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your solution.thanks all the same.@Can,As he said, it works,and better.

Comment: Yes @Can has the real solution, I just told you how this happens.

Comment: At least I won't make this mistake again in the future.thanks.